# Acquire the largest 7 groups after groupby base on index value

Tags: python

The following dataframe was created by using df.groupby(['Name','Total'])
I sorted this by the 'Total' with code .sort_index(level=1)
the last step I need to do is to take of the largerst 7 groups base on the value of 'Total'?

Is there any way I can do it without reseting the index?

I try .get_group but not sure how to get more than one,thanks.

| Name | Total | Model | Inv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 99999 | 145.0 | 42396 |
|  |  | 152.5 | 17800 |
|  |  | 147.0 | 15629 |
|  |  | 157.5 | 11667 |
|  |  | 162.5 | 4881 |
|  |  |  |  |
| B | 88888 | 12.5 | 3892 |
|  |  | 13.0 | 21716 |
|  |  | 12.5 | 15255 |
|  |  | 14.0 | 14013 |
|  |  | 13.5 | 2093 |

.
.
.

| Name | Total | Model | Inv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C | 22222 | 14.5 | 7892 |
|  |  | 15.0 | 51716 |
|  |  | 12.5 | 75255 |
|  |  | 14.0 | 34013 |
|  |  | 13.5 | 1093 |
|  |  |  |  |
| D | 11111 | 145.0 | 42396 |
|  |  | 152.5 | 17800 |
|  |  | 147.0 | 15629 |
|  |  | 157.5 | 11667 |
|  |  | 162.5 | 4881 |

Answer (score 0):

Before(!) using `df.groupby()` you might consider the following code to achieve your goal:

```py
Totals = df.Total.unique()
Totals.sort()
df.loc[df.Total.isin(Totals[-7:]),:]
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I am sure this way works. Is there a way can get the first 10 groups directly？

Comment: My guess `groupby()` is designed for summarizing data from other columns like in R tidyverse, not for filtering. Why do you want to use it for filtering? `DataFrameGroupBy` object doesn't even have a method `.loc()` or `query()` unlike 'pd.DataFrame' to do that. [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html) you can see all of its methods.